# Do Blocked Google Analytics tracking count as bounces?

Tags: google-analytics, bots, bounce

I am seeing a higher number of Linux users come into my site,  with a high bounce rate.

Read that 82% of Linux users block Google Analytics tracking.  Trying to figure out if "blocking" is causing these the register as bounces, or are these possible bots.

Appreciate any insight.

Dug into the metrics looking for reasons for low conversions.  Thought it might be Apple Privacy, but instead it was Linux users.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not blocking. Analytics doesn't see anything when it's blocked.

High bounces with linux useragent are likely just bots parsing your site, especially if the landing pages are different in their sessions. They typically don't bother saving the session/client id cookie.